# Running Script before/after Variables declared?

Tags: php, javascript, html, variables

As i understand javascript .js files are best to put all the way at the bottom of html pages, to speed up loading of rest of page. Advised by Yslow(Yahoo) and Page Speed(google).

Now, when in the middle of page some thing RUNS a javascript script, in Internet Explorer, i see a small warning message saying that the element is: `Uncaught ReferenceError: SWFObject is not defined`

When i put my all.js file in the had, the error goes away but page load slows doen. What to do?

Actually, i remember it was the same with php variables. If i RUN php but the variable comes later, then it just doesnt work. must define the variable first, for it to run.

**How to make this workflow better, in case of php scripts? and in case of javsscripts?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put your library scripts that are external in the head (things like swfobject, jquery, etc.). But the actual function call you make (for example to bind an event with jquery, or to initialize a swfobject embed) should go at the end.

This made even esier if you keep calling global functions outside of an event handler to a minium and dont use inline javascript or global variables.

Answer (score 1):

What is that "some thing" that runs javascript in the middle of the page?
We do not use `<script>` tags, and all javascript code we put is js files, which are loaded in strict sequences (so I definitely know that when code is executed, everything it uses is there). (ok, to speed up page loading we append all files into few, like probably you do, "all.js")
If you use script in html attributes (like `onchange` events etc.) then try to use [unobtrussive javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) (attach your events from javascript files).
If that does not help, then divide your javascript into few parts - minimum needed to load the page and execute some stuff before other part is loaded (in `<head>` of page). Bigger part of scripts you will load before `</body>`